# Why doesn't this Python pandas code work on my dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I am a newbie in data science, and I encountered a problem about pandas in Python. Basically, I want to substitute the value lower than 0 in a column with 0, and I wonder why this does not work:

Image of my dataset: dataset:
[image: dataset]

Original:

```
submit[submit.score<0].score = 0
```

Fixed:

```
submit.loc[submit.score<0, 'score'] = 0
```

I have already solved this problem by using iloc, but it really confuses me. Any explanation would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt is equivalent to `submit[submit['score'] < 0]['score'] = 0`. Whenever you see multiple `[` and `]` pairs in your pandas code, it might be a bad sign. In this case, with `submit[submit['score'] < 0]` you're creating a copy of your dataframe, so you're basically assigning `0` to the `score` column *on that copy*, which isn't going to do anything.

By using `loc`, you eliminate the copy and assign directly to the dataframe.

Comment: thanks for your quick response! What if I want to stick with using mask? What   can i do?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but your second attempt is using a mask properly, and you should use that one. It's very Pythonic.

Comment: So you would recommend using loc instead of multiple brackets for masking, right? Since my first attempt create redundant copy, there is no need for that. I just found out that "submit[submit.score<0] = 5" can change  both the original id and score to 5. How is that?

Comment: `submit[submit.score<0] = 5` changes all the columns because you're basically assigning `5` to each column where `score < 0`. And yes, I definitely recommend using `.loc` instead of multiple brackets.

Comment: You mentioned that using "submit[submit['score'] < 0]['score'] = 0" is creating a copy, so assigning new value would not affect the original one. However, in "submit[submit.score<0] = 5, I could change the original data. How is that? Are these two  the same?

Comment: In the first, by using the second pair of brackets, you create a copy, then you assign. In the second code, you assign while indexing essentially, so no copy is created.

Comment: Wow, adding another [] means creating a copy. Sounds pretty unstraightforward to me. If that is its mechanism, I'd better stick with loc. Thanks bro, have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.loc` is good, like the sibling answer says.

Even better, sometimes, is to use chaining operations where you create new objects instead of mutating another in-place. This leads to code that is easy to read and follow.

I would suggest the following:

```py
submit = submit.assign(score=submit.score.clip(0, None))
```

It's still just one line, but it makes a new dataframe with the `score` column replaced. The `.clip()` method is used to clamp the values into an interval, in this case so that anything less than 0 will be zero.

This style makes it easy to add more operations in a chain (a style seen other places).

Comment: Do you know why "submit[submit.score<0] = 5" would change the value of my original submit and "submit[submit.score<0].score = 0" wouldn't? Based on @richardec 's answer, I thought these two are manipulating with the copy of my original data. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the answer is in https://realpython.com/pandas-settingwithcopywarning/

Comment: Thanks! Really Really useful and thorough. Sorry for not upvoting your answer because of my low reputation.

Comment: Hehe that's fine, that's unfortunately how SO is. You got my upvote for the question and will have to wait for further votes (voters are quite stingy here I think)